# Tuning sound for human speech

Tags: sound

I never use the audio in my laptop for music. It is used for zoom meetings, youtube lectures, etc. So I'd like to optimise it for human speech legibility. Is there an equaliser or sound profile or similar that does that? I know of PulseEffects, but can't find a profile tuned for human voices.